# php msgpack_pack and how to convert in Unity3d C#

Tags: php, json, unity-game-engine, msgpack

I wonder why using msgpack do not encrypt in php.

I think "{"id":1,"v1":"bla","v2":"foo"}" will convert to hex string "83 a2 69 64 01 a2 76 31 a3 62 6c 61 a2 76 32 a3 66 6f 6f"

But the result is "魷"id":1,"v1":"bla","v2":"foo"}"
why?

This is my code below:

```
include_once "msgpack.php";
$phpVariable = array( "id"=>1, "v1"=>'bla',"v2"=> 'foo');
$json = json_encode($phpVariable,true);
echo $json."<br>";//{"id":1,"v1":"bla","v2":"foo"}
$binaryString = msgpack_pack($json);
echo $binaryString."<br>";//魷"id":1,"v1":"bla","v2":"foo"}
$base64 = base64_encode($binaryString);
echo $base64."<br>";//vnsiaWQiOjEsInYxIjoiYmxhIiwidjIiOiJmb28ifQ==

------------output-----------------------
{"id":1,"v1":"bla","v2":"foo"}
魷"id":1,"v1":"bla","v2":"foo"}
vnsiaWQiOjEsInYxIjoiYmxhIiwidjIiOiJmb28ifQ==
```

If I only use php msgpack,don't use json_encode,
but I don't know how to convert decodedBytes in Unity3d C#.

```
//php code
$data = (object) array('name' => 'peter', 'age' => '30');//this could be a multi array
$msgpack_response = msgpack_pack($data);
$msgpack_response = base64_encode($msgpack_response);
echo $msgpack_response;

 //Unity3d C# use msgpack 
 byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String (text);
 ObjectPacker packer = new ObjectPacker ();
 ??? data = packer.Unpack<???>(decodedBytes);//I don't know the type and how to convert?
```

Comment: Why are you expecting msgpack to "encrypt"? It is not an encryption library.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to use msgpack to shorten response message bytes,and  the response message can't use base64_decode to convert to clear code Ex:魷"id":1,"v1":"bla","v2":"foo"}

Answer (score 0):

msg_pack is a binary serializer. So result of `msgpack_pack` must be a binary string and it useless just to echo it to wonder what is in side.

Any way. `$json` variable is a string. According this [type overview](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#overview) msgpack will add prefix to your string `fixstr 101xxxxx 0xa0 - 0xbf`.

Length of string is 30 so `1010 0000(2) + 0000 1110(2) = 1011 1110(2) = BE(16)`. So first byte of result will `BE`.

Then, you trying to echo binary string as multibyte string. It captures two first bytes as one symbol.